# MusicPlayer only plays one track

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, midi

So, I'm loading in a multi-track .mid file to be played using the MusicPlayer API. It's working fine with single track .mid files but when I tried to use a .mid with two tracks, it didn't synthesize the audio for track 2 but it did for track 1.

I know that the track is there, and I know that it is recognized by the system because I am adding user events at all of the noteMessage events that display what note is being played. My keys light up like the notes are being played, but there is no sound.

***EDIT***

So, I've been doing some digging. Turns out it is actually playing the track. The problem is, the default AUPreset for the Sampler that is automatically generated when you create the sequence, doesn't have any proper tones for notes below middle C.

So, this question becomes, are there AUPresets that one can download somewhere or do you have to make your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the default instrument that the MusicPlayer uses is a sine-wave based tone generator. The tones much below middle C are so low that they are pretty much inaudible. So, for future reference, when one is using the MusicPlayer API, you have to load in your own instrument if you want to use the entire key range.